# TCP Windowsize 0 after FIN packet

Tags: networking, tcp, plc

Is it okay if a machine sets the TCP windowsize to zero after receiving a FIN?

I've got the following packet dump from wireshark of the end of the connection and I'm just wondering if this is a valid way to end a connection or if something is wrong.

```
192.168.1.1 192.168.1.6 TCP 3450 > 102 [FIN, ACK] Seq=48 Ack=50 Win=65486 Len=0
192.168.1.6 192.168.1.1 TCP [TCP ZeroWindow] 102 > 3450 [ACK] Seq=50 Ack=49 Win=0 Len=0
192.168.1.6 192.168.1.1 TCP 102 > 3450 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=50 Ack=49 Win=0 Len=0
192.168.1.1 192.168.1.6 TCP 3450 > 102 [ACK] Seq=49 Ack=51 Win=65486 Len=0
```

BTW: .1 is a regular windows PC while .6 is a Siemens PLC. (S7-400)

---

After some investigation it looks like a weird but valid way to end a TCP conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with sending a zero window after a `FIN ACK`... presumably `192.168.1.6` sent a `FIN` to `192.168.1.1`, so they are now closing the connection.

`192.168.1.6 192.168.1.1 TCP [TCP ZeroWindow] 102 > 3450 [ACK] Seq=50 Ack=49 Win=0 Len=0`

But immediately setting a `PSH` flag and sending no data (Len=0) right after that `ACK`, looks rather odd (but not technically wrong) to me...

`192.168.1.6 192.168.1.1 TCP 102 > 3450 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=50 Ack=49 Win=0 Len=0`

Comment: @Mike, I think you are wrong about the meaning of the `PSH` flag. See, for example, here http://www.daemon.org/tcp.html

Comment: @Nikolai, what are you specifically saying is wrong?  Your link agrees with what I said AFAICT.

Comment: 192.168.1.1 sends the first FIN (first line). 192.168.1.6 then responds with an ACK packet immediately followed by a second ACK with FIN set.

Comment: The push flag is for the receiving TCP/IP stack to "push data to the receiving application as soon as possible" - not for it to send data back to the sender over the wire.

Comment: @grimming, that is not how TCP works.  The sequence is one side initiates with a `FIN`, then the other side *acknowledges the `FIN`* with a `FIN ACK`.

Comment: @mike PSH is saying to the *receiving* TCP stack "I'm done, push this data to the receiving application". Your wording makes it sound like the data should be pushed to the sender.

Comment: Actually none of the code I can control is involved here. The reason I'm asking is to make sure that this is a valid TCP handshake and the problem we're looking for is somewhere else.

Comment: Lost data during transmission, but that is not part of the question. I was trying to exclude the TCP connection as the cause and those packets looked a bit suspicious. The packet dump came to me along with a claim that the PLC (192.168.1.6) had run out of buffer space because it reduced the windowsize to 0. (But even if that was true that wouldn't matter since the other side already closed the connection.)  So the only question remaining is, if the above dump is a valid TCP sequence or a violation of RFCs.

Comment: @grimmig, you should be able to look at this capture in wireshark (GUI), filter for packets sent in that TCP stream to whichever side has the data loss problem. Then, goto "Analyze -> Follow TCP Stream".  Compare those results with what the application says it is getting.  This will tell you whether the data was sent.  I will need to check the RFC to be 100% sure for the session close sequence.

Comment: If it were so simple. We don't know what's lost since it's an intermittent phenomenon that's not reproduceable and we don't have direct access to the site. It has just been declared somebody else's problem since half of the software running there isn't ours and we didn't change anything. Back to topic: From my digging through RFCs and docs I found that this should be valid, although a bit weird. It's a half-closed connection where the client closes the connection and the server decides to set a 0 window size on the remaining half of the connection before closing it.

Comment: @grimmig, shouldn't you be able to pick one site that has consistent problems and either sniff all traffic to/from the appropriate server (logging to disk)?